# How to delete a Firebase Storage folder from a Firebase Cloud Function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I couldn't find the `deleteFiles()` method in the Firebase API reference. My IDE tells me this method takes an optional `DeleteFilesOptions` argument and I couldn't find any information on that type as well. If someone could point me to this documentation I would appreciate it.

That said, I've seen a number of posts that use this method, with this argument, to delete an entire Storage folder (and all of its files) through a Cloud Function. My question is, is this the correct way to do it (since the documentation here is missing)?

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

exports.deleteStorageFolder = functions.https.onCall(async (data, _context) => {
    const uid = data.userId;

    try {
        const bucket = admin.storage().bucket(); // returns the default bucket, which is good
        await bucket.deleteFiles({
            prefix: `images/users/${uid}`, // the path of the folder
        });
        return Promise.resolve(true);
    } catch (error) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError("unknown", "Failed to delete storage folder.", error);
    }
});
```

Comment: It's correct if the works the way you expect.  Stack Overflow is for questions about something that isn't working the way you expect.  If you want someone to review your code that is already working correctly, post to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.  If this code is not working the way you expect, please edit the question to provide your debugging information.

Comment: @DougStevenson well I haven't run it yet because I don't want it to delete my entire bucket. Also, what is the difference between Firebase Storage and Google Cloud Storage? I see these terms used what appears to be interchangably?

Comment: You can run a node script on your local machine in order to experiment with any APIs in a safe environment. Firebase just provides wrappers around Cloud Storage.  They are the same thing.

Comment: @kidcoder, have you checked my posted answer? Let us know if you have any clarifications or questions. Lastly, see: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Doug already mentioned in the comment, "Firebase just provides wrappers around Cloud Storage. They are the same thing.". Also, according to this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage#how_does_it_work), "Cloud Storage for Firebase stores your files in a Google Cloud Storage bucket, making them accessible through both Firebase and Google Cloud. This allows you the flexibility to upload and download files from mobile clients via the Firebase SDKs for Cloud Storage."

Having been said that, I've tried replicating the code snippet you've provided using `deleteFiles()`, and it worked fine on my end:

```
// // The Firebase Admin SDK to access Firestore.
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

const firebaseConfig = {
    // Your Firebase configuration...
};

admin.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();
async function deleteFolder(){
    await bucket.deleteFiles({
    prefix: 'images/users/${uid}'   // the path of the folder
    });
}

deleteFolder();
```

One another option that you can do is to directly use Google Cloud Storage, and skip using the Firebase Storage:

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage();
const bucket = storage.bucket("your-bucket-name");

bucket.deleteFiles({
  prefix: 'images/users/${uid}'
}, function(err) {
  if (!err) {
    console.log("All files in the `images` directory have been deleted.");    
  }
});
```

Just a note, following the suggestion of Doug, you can try and test it out first in your local or test environment. For further reference, you can refer to [delete()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#delete) and [deleteFiles()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#deleteFiles)